# Which statement does actually "integration by substitution" motivate?

Tags: calculus

I know how to calculate integration by substitution, and I kind of understand it very good if it is presented with a precise notation. For example, I understand pretty well that it says the following: $$ \left(\left.\int f(t)\,dt\right)\right|_{t=g(x)}=\int f(g(x))g'(x)\,dx. $$

But in school we got it presented in the following way: $$ \int f(g)\,dg=\left\{ dg=g'(x)\,dx \right\}=\int f(g)g'(x)\,dx. $$ But I'm not quite sure how this is working. Doesn't integration by substitution directly imply the equality (1): $$ \int f(g)\,dg=\int f(g)g'(x)\,dx $$ ? Or is maybe the "equality" $dg=g'(x)\,dx$ just a notational formalism that is supposed to mean exactly that (1) holds? And thus is more like a convenient notation for remembering the rule?

Comment: I would say none of that is very good. At this level, all you're doing is the chain rule in reverse. So if $F(u) = \int f(u)\,du,$ which is the same as saying $F'=f,$ then $\int f(g(x))g'(x)\,dx = F(g(x).$ Why? Simply differentiate and use the chain rule.

Comment: I understand that, and that is exactly the first equation I wrote. I'm not looking for why integration by substitution is true, but rather why it can be motivated in the differential notation. I'm not sure exactly which step in the "non-rigorous" version with differentials that the "chain rule in reverse" motivates, though.

Comment: Well the  $|_{t=g(x)}$ business looked a bit weird to me.

Comment: @zhw. Oh! That just means that I substitute $t$ with $g(x)$ in the expression I get.

Comment: I know, it just looked weird to me.

Comment: Once you understand the substitution $t=g(x)$ it is no need to introduce the new name $t$, just write $g=g(x)$ and the integral becomes the same.